# Not getting the result from query properly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written the following `query`.

```
select 
  count (distinct asset.assetId) 
from 
  Asset asset 
  left join asset.assetTitles title  
  left join asset.distTypes distTypes
where 
  title.program.id in (:progIdParam) 
  and distTypes in (:lkpDistTypeId) 
  and asset.active = 1
  and asset.isShow = 1
  and asset.classification = 'Internal Use'
```

I call it using:

```
 private Long assetTitleListForIp = 0L;

 assetTitleListForIp = (Long)entityManager
      .createQuery(query)                                 
      .setParameter("progIdParam",progId)
      .setParameter("lkpDistTypeId",LookupValueEnum.DIST_TYPE_INTL_PRODUCTION.getLkpId())
      .getSingleResult();
```

If I take the query fired in eclipse console and run it in DB, it is showing count as 1. But in application, for assetTitleListForIp  it is assigning value as zero. I am not getting the small mistake I have done. Can anybody help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `assetTitleListForIp` is field. I suspect your problem has nothing to do with the query itself. Posible issues:

- the query is run an all and all you see is the initial value of `assetTitleListForIp`
- `assetTitleListForIp` is masked by a local variable in the method doing the query
- you're reading the field `assetTitleListForIp` from some other instance of the object holding that field.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have casting problem. `getSingleResult()` doesn't directly cast to `Long`.  Try to get result as follows:

```
Object countObj=entityManager.createQuery(
               "select count (distinct asset.assetId) from Asset asset left join "+
               "asset.assetTitles title  left join asset.distTypes distTypes where "+
               "title.program.id in (:progIdParam) and distTypes in (:lkpDistTypeId) "+
               "and asset.active =1 and asset.isShow = 1 and asset.classification "+
               "='Internal Use'")
               .setParameter("progIdParam",progId)
               .setParameter("lkpDistTypeId",
               LookupValueEnum.DIST_TYPE_INTL_PRODUCTION.getLkpId())
               .getSingleResult();

Long count=Long.valueOf(""+countObj);
assetTitleListForIp=count;
```